# Java distributed client-server application + rdbms and concurrency issues

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, concurrency

In the context of a university project, we have to develop a Java distributed application with these requirements:

- The application will follow the classic client-server schema, with
  multiple clients connecting to a central server on a different
  machine, which also hosts a rdbms to which the server connects
- The relational database we must use is postgresql (latest version)
- Both client and server must be written in Java
- We must use native JDBC to access the database (we can't use frameworks like Spring)

DISCLAIMER:please understand we are just a group of students and this is our first big project involving all these aspects and we aren't experts by any means, so please be patient with us :) (also English is not our first language, sorry for any mistake you might find)

We are currently in the design phase of the application (class diagrams, sequence diagrams etc) and we're stuck with a possible concurrency problem with the database:
ideally our server would listen for any requests and for each client that logs in the application, the server launches a dedicated thread that provides implemented services to the user (implementing pattern proxy-skeleton with basic socket programming). Each of these service providers (threads), upon completing the requested task should update/insert/delete data to the database. Here is the problem: how should we manage the concurrency here?
We tried to search the internet for this kind of issue and we found some things but we're still very confused:

- Since we actually interact with the database from one single central
  server (with one admin profile) we could implement a queue sistem for
  the various transactions coming from the different threads we
  launched
- We manage concurrency at database level with some well-known mechanism such as MVCC, which is apparently a lot more complicated

Ideally we would like that read requests don't block other reads or writes, and writes only block other writes (which seems to be the case with MVCC). Which alternative would be best? Are there any other options that we could implement with the restrictions above mentioned? Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: Normally these concerns are handled at the database layer by using the correct transaction isolation level suitable for your purpose. Is that not an option in this case?

Comment: Yes it would be an option but we don't really know how to realize that in practice. Let's suppose we use JDBC with DAO pattern, should we implement transactions and MVCC via the Java app? Sorry we've never done this before so it's really not clear what we should do

Comment: In that case, I suggest you learn about transactions and transaction isolation levels. The right way to do this would be to use a transaction for database updates so clients cannot damage the work done by others. The transaction isolation level will determine if and how you can see uncommitted data.

Comment: ok, thanks we'll definetly look into that topic and learn more